# Can you determine if an interaction exists from a correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, interaction

Below are the results of a correlational analysis. This table shows the correlations among 8 variables (`performance expectancy`, `effort expectancy`, `social influence`, `perceived playfulness` and `self management of learning` are independent variables, `behavioral intention` is the dependent variable and `age` and `gender` are moderator variables). In this research, the correlation between dependent variable and independent variables were measured. Based on the results, can I say that age and gender moderated the correlation between each dependent and independent variables? What are the age and gender relations with each variable?

```
       Mean  SD      PE     EE      SI       PP     SM       BI    Age      Gender 
PE     4.41  1.15   0.77                            
EE     4.75  1.06   0.45    0.75                        
SI     3.97  1.78   0.51    0.23    0.72                    
PP     5.28  0.95   0.57    0.58    0.38    0.81                
SM     5.09  1.09   0.42    0.39    0.29   -0.24    0.71            
BI     4.89  1.33   0.47    0.35    0.34    0.31    0.45     0.84       
Age   34.45 11.72   0.06    0.05   -0.04   -0.10    0.09    -0.12   NA  
Gender 8.06  2.34  -0.09   -0.05    0.03    0.08    0.04    -0.19   0.24    NA
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot tell if there is moderation from this table.  Moderation / an interaction, means that the effect of the independent variables on the dependent variables differs based on which level of the moderator variable holds for some data.  It may be possible to get a basic intuition if you had multiple correlation matrices that were stratified by your moderator variable (e.g., if you had one correlation matrix for when `Gender` was male and one for when `Gender` was female), but not from this.